# получение данных из очереди в заданном порядке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вопрос в том что `part` разной длины и грубо говоря если `data[0]` больше чем `data[1]`, то `data[1]` достаётся раньше из очереди, а мне бы хотелось чтобы были по порядку, как `part` идут. Ждать пока `data[0]` будет готова, поместить её в выходную очередь, а потом уже `data[1]` туда положить, посоветуйте как такое реализовать.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from queue import Queue

def func(data):
    rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, sample_rate)
    for part in data:
        if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
            queue.put(rec.Result())
        else:
            rec.PartialResult()
        if rec.FinalResult() != '':
            queue.put(rec.FinalResult())
    return

with Pool as pool:
    pool.map(func, data)

    while not queue.empty():
        print(queue.get())
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139672/discussion-on-question-by-iliketea-------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, по результатам дискуссии, на мой взгляд правильнее было бы сделать так, вообще без очереди. Данные в этом случае должны получиться в том же порядке, в каком они отправлялись в `pool`:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from queue import Queue

def func(data):
    rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, sample_rate)
    result = []
    for part in data:
        if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
            result.append(rec.Result())
        else:
            rec.PartialResult()
        if rec.FinalResult() != '':
            result.append(rec.FinalResult())
    return result

with Pool() as pool:
    for result in pool.map(func, data):
        for item in result:
            print(result)
```